# Why does ContinueWith return Task<Task<x>>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have a method, `GetSomethingAsync`, that is `return Task<MyTypeA>.Run(() => GetSomething());`

I have another method, `GetSomethingElseAsync`, that is `return Task<MyTypeB>.Run(() => GetSomethingElse());`

I want the second task to run conditionally, based on something from the first, so I have

```
var task1 = GetSomethingAsync();
var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(x =>
    x.Result == null ? Task.FromResult(null) : GetSomethingElseAsync());
```

`task2` compiles as a `Task<Task<MyTypeB>>`. I was expecting `Task<MyTypeB>`. Is it possible to get my expected result?

Comment: It returns only `Task`, other one is part of your lambda, that's why `Task<Task<...>>`

Comment: Don't use `ContinueWith` for things like this, use `await`, which makes writing correct code *much* easier.

Comment: both `Task.FromResult` and `GetSomethingElseAsync` return a `Task`. if you need to get the result of `task2` just `await` for it.

Comment: `var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(r => r.Result == null ? null : GetSomethingElseAsync().ContinueWith(r2 => r2.Result));`

Comment: @WiktorZychla `task2` in your case is *also* a `Task<Task<MyTypeB>>`.  The only difference in your case is that you've messed up the error handling a bit.

Comment: @Servy: my bad, it was supposed to be `var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(r => r.Result == null ? null : GetSomethingElseAsync().ContinueWith(r2 => r2.Result).Result);`. However, I am not sure the latter async can't be simplified in this syntax.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Now you're synchronously blocking until the asynchronous operation complete, when it should be done asynchronously.  Your added continuation is just as pointless as it was before (and is still harming the error handling) the only difference is now you've added in a synchronous wait of the task.

Comment: @Servy: are you sure? The latter `ContinueWith` is blocked, not the `GetSomethingelseAsync`, that's why `.Result` only after it's available.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Waiting on a continuation that returns the result of asynchronous operation is only different from waiting on the asynchronous operation itself if there is an exception or it's cancelled.  In either of those cases you will return an incorrect exception (it'll be a wrapped aggregate exception).  Outside of that improper error handling there's no observable difference between waiting on a continuation that does nothing useful and waiting on the original task.

Comment: @Servy: nice one, what about `var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(r => r.Result == null ? null : GetSomethingElseAsync()).Unwrap()`?

Comment: @WiktorZychla That will through an exception at runtime because `UnWrap` doesn't support tasks that have a null inner task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

```
var task1 = GetSomethingAsync();
```

is defined with async and returns a `Task<T>`.

And the signature of [ContinueWith()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx) is

```
public Task<TResult> ContinueWith<TResult>(
  Func<Task, TResult> continuationFunction
)
```

Now focusing on your lambda result:

```
x => x.Result == null ? Task.FromResult(null)
```

Reads something like, if the Result of the task is null then return a Task (Task.FromResult).

So your `Func<Task, TResult>` the `TResult` is a `Task<T>` as if the lambda was written as:

```
Task<T> AnonymousFunction(task x)
{
  return ... Task.FromResult(null);
}
```

Now the result of a `ContinueWith()` is a `Task<TResult>` and since we've determine a `TResult` is a `Task<T>` then the result type is `Task<Task<T>>`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [`Unwrap`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap) extension method. This method takes a nested task `Task<Task<T>>`, and flattens it to a `Task<T>`. The unwrapped task represents the completion of both the outer and inner task. If anyone of them fail, the unwrapped task contains the `Exception` that occurred in either task:

```
Task<MyTypeA> task1 = GetSomethingAsync();

Task<MyTypeB> task2 = task1.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    return t.Result is null ?
        Task.FromResult<MyTypeB>(null) : GetSomethingElseAsync();
}).Unwrap();
```

Unfortunately the above code is far from perfect.

1. It violates the guideline CA2008: [Do not create tasks without passing a TaskScheduler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008).
2. It propagates the cancellation of the `task1` as a failure. So if the `task1.IsCanceled`, the `task2` will be `IsFaulted`.
3. It wraps a possible exception of `task1` in a nested `AggregateException`.

Here is the same code corrected:

```
Task<MyTypeA> task1 = GetSomethingAsync();

Task<MyTypeB> task2 = task1.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsFaulted)
        return Task.FromException<MyTypeB>(t.Exception.InnerException);
    if (t.IsCanceled)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<MyTypeB> tcs = new();
        tcs.SetCanceled(new TaskCanceledException(t).CancellationToken);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
    return t.Result is null ?
        Task.FromResult<MyTypeB>(null) : GetSomethingElseAsync();
}, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
```

A simpler solution is to ditch the cumbersome [`ContinueWith`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) method, in favor of the handy [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) language feature:

```
Task<MyTypeA> task1 = GetSomethingAsync();

Task<MyTypeB> task2 = ((Func<Task<MyTypeB>>)(async () =>
{
    MyTypeA result = await task1.ConfigureAwait(false);
    return result is null ? null :
        await GetSomethingElseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}))();
```

This can be simplified even further by using the `Then` family of extension methods that can be found [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-then-with-await/) (by Stephen Toub).

```
Task<MyTypeA> task1 = GetSomethingAsync();

Task<MyTypeB> task2 = task1.Then(async result =>
    result is null ? null : await GetSomethingElseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
```

You can think the `Then` extension method as a [`ContinueWithResult`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/58692), with an argument that contains the result of the antecedent task, instead of the antecedent task itself.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(completedTask => completedTask.Result == null ? (TypeB)null : GetSomethingElse());
```

`task2` should now be of type `Task<MyTypeB>`.

The issue is that `task1.ContinueWith` already returns a `Task<T>`. In your statement, you are also returning a `Task<T>`, or more accurately, a `Task<MyTypeB>`. Hence, the result of the call to `task1.ContinueWith` is `Task<T>` where `T` is `Task<MyTypeB>`. What you see in the debugger: `Task<Task<MyTypeB>>`.

Comment: It's not, however consider adding `Unwrap()` at the end. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-unwrap-a-nested-task

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Thank you for bringing this up. I had a typo. I have since corrected it. `task2` is of type `Task<MyTypeB>` which is what the OP wanted.